# Can we edit Mobile App Salesforce Navigation through code / callouts to Metadata?

Tags: salesforce1-app, metadata, tab, navigation

I have read this Trailhead lesson: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/salesforce1_mobile_app/salesforce1_mobile_app_navigation (Customize the Mobile Only Navigation Menu).

Now I am wondering, **is it possible to add your custom tabs to Salesforce 1 navigation menu not via UI?**

What I have already done:

1) I have added tab through UI and pulled changed metadata, however, there were no changes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_appmenu.htm

It should be under "AppMenu" metadata ("Salesforce1.appMenu"). You should be able to pull the changes and push the changes through metadata with the following structure:

```
<AppMenu xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>MyDay</name>
    <type>StandardAppMenuItem</type>
  </appMenuItems>
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>Tasks</name>
    <type>StandardAppMenuItem</type>
  </appMenuItems>
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>Feed</name>
    <type>StandardAppMenuItem</type>
  </appMenuItems>
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>Dashboards</name>
    <type>StandardAppMenuItem</type>
  </appMenuItems>
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>Search</name>
    <type>StandardAppMenuItem</type>
  </appMenuItems>
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>Events</name>
    <type>StandardAppMenuItem</type>
  </appMenuItems>
  <appMenuItems>
    <name>DE_Widget</name>
    <type>CustomTab</type>
  </appMenuItems>
</AppMenu>
```

Comment: Will check ad accept your answer in case, thank you very much!

Comment: Your solution works for me, appMenus somehow were in my forceignore file. It is said, that I can send you bounty in 5 hours. I will, thank you very much for the hint!